# Error @Autowired an interface with another project

Tags: spring

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MiParteTrabajoDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mydomain.repository.produccion.ParteTrabajoRepository com.mydomain.dao.produccion.ParteTrabajoDaoExample.parteRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mydomain.repository.produccion.ParteTrabajoRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

```
package com.mydomain.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    @Override
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    @Override
    T findOne(ID primaryKey);

    @Override
    List<T> findAll();

    @Override
    long count();
    @Override
    void delete(T entity);
    @Override
    boolean exists(ID primaryKey);
}
```

and

```
package com.mydomain.repository.produccion;

public interface ParteTrabajoRepository extends CrudRepository<PParteTrabajo, PParteTrabajoPK> {

    @Query(value = "select u from PParteTrabajo u where u.idParteTrabajo like %?1", nativeQuery = true)
    public PParteTrabajo findByIdParteTrabajo(int idParteTrabajo);
}
```

and

```
package com.mydomain.dao.produccion;

public interface ParteTrabajoDaoI {

    public List<PParteTrabajo> findAll();
}
```

and

```
package com.mydomain.dao.produccion;

@Repository("MiParteTrabajoDao")
public class ParteTrabajoDaoExample implements ParteTrabajoDaoI {

    @Autowired
    private ParteTrabajoRepository parteRepository;

    @Override
    public List<PParteTrabajo> findAll() {
        final List<PParteTrabajo> lista = parteRepository.findAll();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.mydomain.services.produccion;

import com.mydomain.entities.produccion.PParteTrabajo;
import com.mydomain.util.dao.DaoException;
import com.mydomain.util.exception.FindException;

public interface ParteTrabajoServiceI<T> {

    public T iniciarParteTrabajo(int idMaquina, int idEstacion, int idOperario, int idTrabajo, int idOrden)
            throws FindException;

    public PParteTrabajo iniciarFinalizarParteTrabajo(int idMaquina, int idEstacion, int idOperario, int idTrabajo,
            int idOrden) throws FindException, DaoException;

    public T iniciarParteTrabajoMaquinaTrabajoUnico(int idMaquina, int idOperario, int idOrden) throws FindException,
            DaoException;

    public PParteTrabajo finalizarParteTrabajo(T parteTrabajoIniciado, BigDecimal cantidad) throws DaoException,
            FindException;

    public List<PParteTrabajo> finalizarPartesTrabajosIniciados(int idMaquina, int idOperario) throws FindException,
            DaoException;

    public List<T> getPartesTrabajoIniciados(int idMaquina, int idOperario) throws FindException;

    public List<T> getPartesTrabajoIniciados(int idMaquina) throws FindException;

    public List<T> findAll() throws FindException;

}
```

and

```
package com.mydomain.services.produccion;

import com.mydomain.dao.produccion.ParteTrabajoDaoI;
import com.mydomain.entities.produccion.PParteTrabajo;
import com.mydomain.util.dao.DaoException;
import com.mydomain.util.exception.FindException;

@Service("parteTrabajoServicePrueba")
public class ParteTrabajoServiceExample implements
        ParteTrabajoServiceI<ParteTrabajoServiceExample.ParteTrabajoIniciado> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("MiParteTrabajoDao")
    private ParteTrabajoDaoI parteTrabajoDaoI;

    @Override
    public List<ParteTrabajoIniciado> getPartesTrabajoIniciados(final int idMaquina, final int idOperario) {

        return null;
    }

    public class ParteTrabajoIniciado {
        private final PParteTrabajo parte;

        private ParteTrabajoIniciado(final PParteTrabajo parteTrabajo) {
            parte = parteTrabajo;
        }

        public int getIdOrdenProduccion() {
            return parte.getIdOrdenProduccion();
        } 
    }
....
}
```

and

```
package com.mydomain.iweb;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@Import(com.mydomain.services.ServicesBeanConfig.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("file:etc/application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mydomain.repository,com.mydomain.dao")
public class Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class.getName());

    @Value("${spring.datasource.jndi-name}")
    private String jndiResourceName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.name}")
    private String jdbcName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String jdbcDriverClassName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String jdbcUrl;

    @Inject
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed the bean implementing the ParteTrabajoRepository interface.

`com.mydomain.repository.produccion.ParteTrabajoRepository` is just an interface but it needs a concrete implementation in order for it to be injected with `@Autowired`

Comment: forgive my limited of experience with spring, I created the configuration of services. But I could not be realized as the interface for the DAO.

Answer (score 0):

The value for EnableJpaRepositories is wrong. 
The value is an array, so it should be

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(value ={"com.mydomain.repository","com.mydomain.dao"})
```

The way you declared it spring would try to scan only one package with the name

> "com.mydomain.repository,com.mydomain.dao"

which for sure is not what you want.